# Create a batch file for mac os x that zips multiple files with the same name but different extensions

Tags: batch-file, zip

I have a folder that contains files with the same file name but different extensions (.jpg and .eps). Each .eps has a matching .jpg with the same name and I want to zip them together in pairs. (The zip file should have the same name.)

The naming convention is like this: 1.eps 1.jpg 2.eps 2.jpg ...etc.

I want to create something like this: 1.zip (containing 1.eps and 1.jpg) 2.zip (containing 2.eps and 2.jpg

I am using MAC OS X. I want to automate the process cause I have thousands of files, so an automator workflow would be perfect.

I am currently doing it manually by selecting two files at a time compress them and then rename. So I need something to find the files with the same name automatically within a folder, zip them together in a single zip file, and use the same name for the zip.

Comment: You want a Windows batch file for being executed on a MAC computer? Why do you not create a shell script? Do you have searched at all for `shell zip files` on Stack Overflow or using a www search engine? This is definitely not something new. There are thousands of articles in www which demonstrate how to compress files into a ZIP archive using a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run MS-DOS applications in mac OS X,they are 2 different shells.
Use BASH :

`zip -r foo.zip {Directory/File names here}`

Put that in a .command file